# SQL Naming Convention for ID that joins two tables

Tags: sql, naming-conventions

Im using camel casing for my column names and im trying not to use just ID for the primary key of my tables.

So it seems stait forawrd for some tables like. Profile Table I call the primary key profileID but what about a table that joins two tables together. What is the convention for that ProfileImageID? It seems confusing would it be better to just call it ID? For primary keys is the naming convention just ID or ____ID?

**Profile Table**

```
userID (PK) | Name
```

**Profile Image Table**

```
??? (PK) | userID | photoID
```

**Image Table**

```
photoID(PK) | Image
```

Comment: Why don't you just give the xref table 2 columns of the same name as the other tables (`profileID` and `photoID`)? So you'd have a foreign key for each referencing the same field on each of the other tables, and a PK on `profileID` so that no one profile has 2+ associated photos.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the user id column. So would you call ??? Id or userPhotoID or something else. What is the convention for this?

Comment: I don't see any point in a 3rd column. I'm not sure you really even need a `profile_image` table if you aren't tracking changes to a user's photo over time. If you only need to know what their current photo is, and they can only have one photo, you could just add the `photoID` column to the `profile` table (with a FK to the image table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation:  name the tables in the plural and use the the table name (in singular) plus "Id" for the keys:

```
create table Profiles (
    ProfileId int . . 
);

create table ProfileImages (
    ProfileImageId int . . .,
    ProfileId int references Profiles(ProfileId),
    ImageId int references Images(ImageId)
);

create table Images (
    ImageId int . . .,
    . . .
);
```

There is no one right answer for naming conventions.  But, consistency and understandability are important.  What you should *not* do is have a table called `Images` and a primary key called `PhotoId`.  That just introduces a level of confusion.